# Ember asynchronous routes: how do I display a global loading indicator while waiting for data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route that loads some data from a messy JSON API that is set up according to the [Ember Asynchronous Routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/).

I also have an application controller and template. I want to display a global "Loading..." indicator (or spinner) in the application template whenever an asynchronous route is waiting for data.

Here's a minimal example:

**http://jsbin.com/zorey/6/edit?html,js,output**

How do I notify the application controller from my asynchronous route when loading starts and finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ember's `LoadingRoute`'s `template` and `activate` and `deactivate` hooks for that.

Comment: According to the guide, that's legacy functionality. Wanting to do things in a future-looking way, I never actually read that section because of the big "LEGACY" heading. Having read it now, I see that it explains pretty clearly how to do what I want using non-legacy functionality. So I'll mark this answer accepted. Thanks!